# mysql calculate OT Hours with conditions

Tags: mysql, sum

Hi I have a table otasub.

I need to compute total number of hours (Reg_Hours) but excluding all sundays.

```
ot_plot_date    ot_hr   ot_day     ot_hour_nextday  ot_nextday_day
2015-07-22      2.75    Wednesday   1.5             Thursday
2015-07-23      4.5     Thursday    2.75            Friday
2015-07-25      8       Saturday    3               Sunday
2015-07-19      8       Sunday      1.5             Monday
```

My Query

```
SELECT `ot_plot_date`,`ot_hr`,ot_day, `ot_hour_nextday`,`ot_nextday_day`,
SUM(CASE WHEN otasub.ot_day <> 'Sunday' 
THEN ot_hr + ot_hour_nextday ELSE 0 END) as Reg_Hours
FROM `otasub`
GROUP BY otasub.`ID` , ot_day , ot_type_nextday
```

the result that im getting is this.

```
ot_plot_date    ot_hr   ot_day     ot_hour_nextday  ot_nextday_day Reg_Hours
2015-07-22      2.75    Wednesday   1.5             Thursday       4.25 
2015-07-23      4.5     Thursday    2.75            Friday         7.25
2015-07-25      8       Saturday    3               Sunday         **11**
2015-07-19      8       Sunday      1.5             Monday         1.5
```

The result that I would like to see is this.

```
ot_plot_date    ot_hr   ot_day     ot_hour_nextday  ot_nextday_day Reg_Hours
2015-07-22      2.75    Wednesday   1.5             Thursday       4.25 
2015-07-23      4.5     Thursday    2.75            Friday         7.25
2015-07-25      8       Saturday    3               Sunday         **8**
2015-07-19      8       Sunday      1.5             Monday         1.5
```

Answer (score 0):

The query you are using is giving the answer you should expect because you are using the special "Sunday" logic only when ot_day = 'Sunday' not when ot_nextday_day = 'Sunday'. Perhaps you meant your query to be this:

```
SELECT `ot_plot_date`,`ot_plot_total_hr`,ot_day, `ot_nextday`,`ot_nextday_day`,
SUM(CASE WHEN otasub.ot_nextday_day <> 'Sunday' 
THEN ot_plot_total_hr + ot_nextday ELSE ot_nextday END) as Reg_Hours
FROM `otasub`
GROUP BY otasub.`ID` , ot_day , ot_type_nextday
```

Notice the change in the CASE logic to check ot_nextday_day instead of ot_day.

Also, as a minor point, it looks like the field names in your query do not match the field names in your table structure as you've presented it here. Specifically the ot_plot_total_hr and ot_hour_nextday columns.

Comment: sorry I overlooked already edited the columns,fields. the query you gave does not give me the correct calculation